# Binding a dynamically created CombinedGeometry Path?

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing, shapes

I have an application that draws Slots on the screen as Rectangles with rounded corners. A slot can be part of a Section, which is nothing more than a collection of Slots.

I want to visually mark Slots that have been assigned. So I would like to draw a solid shape covering all selected Slots.

**Before selection:**

[image]

**After selection:**

[image]

The shape **has to be without INNER borders**, so hence the combined geometry.

I really want to bind the CombinedGeometry to the Datatemplate of selected Slots.

**ViewModel**

```
    public ObservableCollection<Slot> Slots
    {
        get { return _slots; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _slots)) return;
            _slots = value;
            DrawShape();
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private void DrawShape()
    {
        Path = new Path();
        Path.Stroke = Brushes.White;
        Path.StrokeThickness = 3;

        var count = Slots.Count();

        var combined = new CombinedGeometry();
        combined.GeometryCombineMode = GeometryCombineMode.Union;

        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                var rect1 = new Rect(Slots[i].PositionX, Slots[i].PositionY, Slots[i].Width, Slots[i].Height);
                var rect2 = new Rect(Slots[i + 1].PositionX, Slots[i + 1].PositionY, Slots[i + 1].Width,
                                     Slots[i + 1].Height);
                combined.Geometry1 = new RectangleGeometry(rect1) { RadiusX = 5, RadiusY = 5 };
                combined.Geometry2 = new RectangleGeometry(rect2) { RadiusX = 5, RadiusY = 5 };
            }
            else
            {
                var rect = new Rect(Slots[i + 1].PositionX, Slots[i + 1].PositionY, Slots[i + 1].Width, Slots[i + 1].Height);
                combined.Geometry1 = combined.Clone();
                combined.Geometry2 = new RectangleGeometry(rect) { RadiusX = 5, RadiusY = 5 };
            }
        }
        Path.Data = combined;
    }
```

**XAML**

```
        <ItemsControl x:Name="DeclaredSections" Margin="20" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Layout.Sections}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Grid/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <!-- DATABIND MY COMBINED SHAPE -->
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: What about `<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=Path}"/>`? I mean that should be part of the `Slot` class, though, and make sure you `NotifyPropertyChange()` accordingly. Though on a second read, I might be misunderstanding your need.

Comment: How would you draw a single combined geometry by the DataTemplate of multiple selected items?